# Is it always possible to inverse the subject and the verb?

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

I am wondering whether we can invert the subject and the verb in english.
Ex (illustrative only):

> A car is provided to the players. The keys must be retrieved at
>   the office.

would become

> Is provided a car to the players, whose keys must be retrieved at the
>   office.
>
> In the house, there exists a gohst

would become

> in the house exists a gohst

Comment: Perhaps you can ask this at our sister site [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), which deals with basic questions for English Language learners.

Comment: Just a brief comment. 'In the house exists a ghost' would work in a fanciful register (ghost / children's stories). 'In the house exists a ghost that has been seen on numerous occasions' sounds much more natural – the added that-clause has this effect. 'In the car park is a car provided for the players' use' is fine. 'Is a car provided for the player's use' only works as a question. 'Is provided a car for the player's use' is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 0):

The keys of the car provided for the players may be collected from the office. This sounds very clumsy to me and you don't really require all the words. (The keys of the car for the players is at the office).

In the house is a ghost. = A ghost is in the house.
(Now, that is an easy one to invert).